# How to ignore left margin and move centered math equation to the left?

Tags: math-mode, lists, margins, indentation

I have a following equation [image]

I need to move it a little bit to the left because it is way to close to the right side and may get clamped while printing.

Those equations are using `$$ R=... $$` syntax. How can I move it to the left ?

**EDIT**

After changing to `\[ ... \]` syntax:

```
\begin{description}
\item[Model matrix] \hfill \\
...
\begin{itemize}
\item Rotation matrix - used to rotate vertex (vertices) by a specifed angle $\alpha$ around specified axis, where each from 3 axes has its own rotation matrix
\[
R_x = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & \cos(\alpha) & -\sin(\alpha) & 0 \\ 0 & \sin(\alpha) & \cos(\alpha) & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix},
\newline
R_y = \begin{bmatrix} \cos(\alpha) & 0 & \sin(\alpha) & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ -\sin(\alpha) & 0 & \cos(\alpha) & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix},
\newline
R_z = \begin{bmatrix} \cos(\alpha) & -\sin(\alpha) & 0 & 0 \\ \sin(\alpha) & \cos(\alpha) & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}
\]
\end{itemize}
```

Comment: You will be punished by the holy mathematical - typographical inquistion if you use `$$...$$`. See (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to)

Comment: Why is that frowned upon? When I changed to `$ ... $` nothing changed

Comment: For comments on `$$...$$` versus `\[...\]` see [why-is-preferable-to](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to?lq=1).

Comment: @Andrew: Too late :-P

Comment: http://ctan.org/pkg/changepage might help?

Answer (score 2):

Adjust for the cumulative indentation of your list by inserting a negative space equivalent to `\@totalleftmargin`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in,showframe]{geometry}% Just for this example
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{description}
  \item[Model matrix] \hfill \\
    \ldots

    \begin{itemize}
      \item Rotation matrix - used to rotate vertex (vertices) by a specifed angle $\alpha$ around specified axis, where each from 3 axes has its own rotation matrix
      \[
        \makeatletter
        \hspace*{-\@totalleftmargin}
        \makeatother
        R_x = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & \cos(\alpha) & -\sin(\alpha) & 0 \\ 0 & \sin(\alpha) & \cos(\alpha) & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix},
        \quad
        R_y = \begin{bmatrix} \cos(\alpha) & 0 & \sin(\alpha) & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ -\sin(\alpha) & 0 & \cos(\alpha) & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix},
        \quad
        R_z = \begin{bmatrix} \cos(\alpha) & -\sin(\alpha) & 0 & 0 \\ \sin(\alpha) & \cos(\alpha) & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}
      \]
    \end{itemize}
\end{description}

\[
  R_x = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & \cos(\alpha) & -\sin(\alpha) & 0 \\ 0 & \sin(\alpha) & \cos(\alpha) & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix},
  \quad
  R_y = \begin{bmatrix} \cos(\alpha) & 0 & \sin(\alpha) & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ -\sin(\alpha) & 0 & \cos(\alpha) & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix},
  \quad
  R_z = \begin{bmatrix} \cos(\alpha) & -\sin(\alpha) & 0 & 0 \\ \sin(\alpha) & \cos(\alpha) & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

Alternatively, move the equation left as much or little as you want. For example, `-\leftmargin` would just remove the deepest indentation.